# Avoid Use of Counter at the Bottom of the Page

Tags: positioning

I have the following counter and I don't want it to be the last item at the bottom of a page. If by any chance the counter happens to be there, then I want it to be moved in the next page as it works something like a title to the content below it.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont
[
  UprightFont = GFSDidot.otf,
  BoldFont = GFSDidotBold.otf,
  ItalicFont = GFSDidotItalic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = GFSDidotBoldItalic.otf,
]{GFSDidot.otf}

\setsansfont{GFSDidot.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newcounter{Counter}

\newcommand{\Count}{\stepcounter{Counter}{\fbox{\large\textbf{\theCounter}}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.

\Count

Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't why you have that counter, but you have to make it sticky, just like a section heading. A section heading will stay with the following text. Are you looking for a section heading? Or a box?

Comment: I suppose the chosen font is irrelevant to the problem? If so, you can remove the font stuff, as many people won't have the font.

Comment: @Johannes_B I like to number things sometimes. I don't want it to be a section header I just want it to have the property you mentioned.

Comment: Currently, `\Count` is the only item on the page, that means it is the first and *last* item. Moving it to the next page does not change it, it is again the last item. Therefore, the document would have to consist of ∞ pages that is not possible. If there is content following, the the problem can be solved by preventing page breaks in between.

Comment: BTW, if the number should be able to be referenced (`\label`/`\ref`), then `\refstepcounter` should be used instead of `\stepcounter`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I don't want this to happen in the MWE. I just added it so you can use the counter. I want this behaviousr when there is text above it and the counter happens to be at the end of the page.

Comment: Adam, please use package `blindtext` and the command `\blindtext` (package `lipsum` gives an alternative) to make your example document useful and show the issue you want to be solved.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did it and I edited my question. What I mean is that the counter now is at the bottom of the page so I don't want it to be there with no content below it so it should automatically move to the next page.

Comment: `\needspace` might be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent a page break before the next paragraph the same way other headings prevent a page break, with `\par\nobreak\@afterheading`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont
[
  %UprightFont = GFSDidot.otf,
  BoldFont = GFSDidotBold.otf,
  ItalicFont = GFSDidotItalic.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = GFSDidotBoldItalic.otf,
]{GFSDidot.otf}

\setsansfont{GFSDidot.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newcounter{Counter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Count}{\stepcounter{Counter}{\fbox{\large\textbf{\theCounter}}}\par\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.

\Count

Ut imperdiet,enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.

\end{document}
```

[image]